# updating multiple tables mysql optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple tables that use the same column called "Team".  I created a update statement but *very slow* and takes way to long.  Can I get some tips to optimize and run faster?

```
update QB, RB, WR, passing, rushing, receiving
set qb.team='GB',
rb.team='GB',
wr.team='GB',
passing.team='GB',
rushing.team='GB',
receiving.team='GB'
where qb.team=('GNB') or
(rb.team='GNB') or
(wr.team='GNB') or 
(passing.team='GNB') or
(rushing.team='GNB') or
(receiving.team='GNB');
```

Comment: Why not just use 6 different update statements instead of mashing them all into one?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a huge cross join on all six of your tables. This means that the criteria in your `WHERE` clause are scanning through a very large number of joined rows. Specifically you're scanning the product of the number of rows in all six tables.

Instead, you should write your query like this.

update QB
     join RB ON QB.something = RB.something
     join WR ON QB.something = WR.something ... etc
      SET QB.team = 'GB', RB.team='GB'  ... etc
    WHERE something